# Why is causal order not related to directionality of time?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, causality, arrow-of-time

Hans Reichenbach argues for the causality and causal chain to define a topological coordinative definition of time order. Here is an excerpt from his textbook, *The Philosophy of Space and Time*, Dover(1957), pp.138

> Another example: We throw a stone from A to B. If we mark the
> stone with a piece of chalk at A, it will carry the same mark when it
> strives at B (event E2). If we mark the stone only on its arrival at B, then the stone leaving A (event E1) has no mark.

> This distinction appears trivial, but it is extremely significant. A
> theory of causality which ignores this elementary difference has
> neglected the most essential aspect. The procedure which we have
> described is used constantly in everyday life to establish a time order,
> and we have no other method in many scientific investigations where
> time intervals are too short to be directly observable. We must
> therefore include the mark principle in the foundations of the theory
> of time.

> We have in the above principle a criterion for causal order that does
> not employ the direction of time, and we can therefore use it in our
> definition of time order. There exists a topological coordinative
> definition for time order. We can base it in general on the concept of
> the causal chain, in which the order of events corresponds to the order
> of time. Occasionally one speaks also of signals or signal chains.
> It should be noted that the word "signal" means the transmission of
> signs and hence concerns the very principle of causal order which we
> have discussed.

My issue is, isn't he implicitly assuming prior and later time, i.e, the time order in defining the causal events? Isn't the mark principle takes into account the time ordering? How is this decoupled from the time ordering?

Comment: I did post the same question at Philosophy SE since I have no idea which place this should fit. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/99229/45976

Comment: As far as I see this pertains to physics in that we discovered that there are two senses to talk about the "order" of events: the *causal* order is something which you can't muck around with, it remains the same for all observers. But the order of events which are not causally related is *not* a globally defined one and observers in different states of motion / positions will generally disagree on that.  More on this subject here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303849/how-does-causality-agree-with-order-of-events

Answer (score 0):

The excerpt you show isn't sufficient to tell what Reichenbach is talking about. The bit you need is in the previous two pages, where he defines the mark principle and what he means by cause and effect.

> If $E_1$ is the cause of $E_2$, then a small variation (a mark) in $E_1$ is associated with a small variation in $E_2$, whereas small variations in $E_2$ are not associated with variations in $E_1$.
>
> If we wish to express even more clearly that this formulation does not contain the concept of temporal order, we can express it in the following form, where the events that show a slight variation are designated by $E^*$.
>
> We observe only the combinations $E_1E_2$, $E_1^*E_2^*$, $E_1E_2^*$ and never the combination $E_1^*E_2$.
>
> In this arrangement the two events are asymmetrical and therefore it defines an *order*. That event which appears in the unobserved combination without an asterisk, namely $E_2$, is called the *effect* and furthermore the *temporally later* event.

It's an very bad definition of cause/effect, but it doesn't assume temporal order. You can perform an experiment lots of times, collect statistics on correlations between events, and when you find a pair of events where one combination doesn't ever occur, you can declare one to be the effect of the other, and later in time.

It (sort of) works for the examples he picks. However, it's not hard to find examples where this definition gives completely the wrong answer, as we ordinarily understand causality. The 'mark principle' is tantamount to saying that marks are made but never erased. Either no mark is made, or a mark has already been made before *either* event, or there is initially no mark and later there is, but you never see a mark disappear. So you just need a pair of events where marks get erased as a counterexample.

I think the underlying idea of the 'mark principle' is to take advantage of the second law of thermodynamics. By 'marks' or 'small variations' he really means *entropy*, and he is relying on entropy always increasing. Things get scrambled but never unscrambled - small variations ('marks') arise but never spontaneously disappear. (You could also call them 'memories' or 'records' instead, which might be a bit clearer about the intention, although the language is obviously less neutral.) However, I think the second law and the definition of entropy have a quite different meaning to his simple 'mark' definition.

Comment: I agree with you that to know what Reichenbach talks about, you need previous two pages, but I was unsure if I could lift multiple pages from the book and post here that may or may not violate Terms of Use, so I put one alone. Also, most people who would attempt to answer might have read his work or have access to it, so I assumed this ending part is enough. Your answer sounds explanatory but I still have an itch about this explanation, so I am keeping this question open for some more time.

Comment: and addressing the problem at hand, even identifying the asymmetry and defining one as cause and other as effect still has the temporality of the causal link embedded in the definition. because how could you explain mark made on event a is also in b but made on b is not on a?

Comment: I think the view on this site is they prefer quotes from references to be searchable text rather than images. If you like, I guess you could copy the text I quoted into your question. I have no problem with you leaving it open as long as you like - it's against my principles to collect 'reputation' points anyway. (Feedback's nice, though.) As for the itch - yes, his definition of 'mark' probably carries a lot of implicit, unspoken temporal assumptions. But he doesn't specify, so I can't comment.

Comment: "because how could you explain mark made on event a is also in b but made on b is not on a?" For the purposes of *definition*, you don't have to. (It's a separate question as to whether and why this definition is equivalent to our everyday definition - which I think may be what you're asking. To claim this definition captures our everyday understanding of time order is to assume marks never disappear. His definition doesn't rely on time order but our everyday understanding does. Since it's *not* equivalent, I'm not sure that can be sensibly answered.)